# Sort XML nodes by child node, then sort different child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I am attempting to create an XSLT file that will create a new XML from a source XML that will sort the types nodes by name, then sort the members inside of each types.

**Source:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Ontario</members>
        <members>Quebec</members>
        <members>Alberta</members>
        <name>Provinces</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Vancouver</members>
        <members>Calgary</members>
        <members>Toronto</members>
        <members>Montreal</members>
        <name>Cities</name>
    </types>
    <version>43.0</version>
</Package>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Calgary</members>
        <members>Montreal</members>
        <members>Toronto</members>
        <members>Vancouver</members>
        <name>Cities</name>
    </types>    
    <types>
        <members>Alberta</members>
        <members>Ontario</members>
        <members>Quebec</members>
        <name>Provinces</name>
    </types>
    <version>43.0</version>
</Package>
```

I started by trying to sort the types by name but it doesnt seem to be sorting anything for me

**XSL:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Package">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="types">
                <xsl:sort select="name"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script failed because you have forgotten about namespaces.
E.g. template matching `Package` refers to this name in the
**empty** namespace, whereas your input `Package` element is
in `http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata` namespace.

So the proper XSLT script should:

- include this namespace in `stylesheet` tag, specyfying a prefix (e.g. `m`),
- refer to tag names using just this prefix.

Below you have a working script:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:m="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="m:Package">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="m:types">
        <xsl:sort select="m:name"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[local-name() != 'types']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="m:types">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="m:members">
        <xsl:sort select="."/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="m:name"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see, I added a template matching `types`, to provide
sort for `members`, just as you specified.

Comment: sorry, this isnt copying over the <version> node at the end

Comment: I added `xsl:apply-templates` for elements with `local-name()` other than `types` and now it is OK.

Comment: I added some case-order and removed omit-xml-declaration="yes" and this works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: another question, is there a way to keep the output formatted as tab delimited?

Comment: To produce tab separated output, you should use `xsl:output method="text"`. Then each piece of output should be generated with `xsl:text`. For details search the Web, I think that even stackoverflow
contains some useful hints.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Package">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="yes">
            <xsl:for-each select="types">
                <xsl:sort select="." order="descending"/>
                <types>
                    <xsl:for-each select="members">
                        <xsl:sort order="ascending"/>
                        <members>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </members>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                    </name>
                </types>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="version"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="version">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
Check it
```

Comment: ` Error reported by XML parser: The prefix "xsl" for element "xsl:output" is not bound.`
`lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 40; The prefix "xsl" for element "xsl:output" is not bound.`